# async hook stack has become corrupted

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous

Am getting this strange error and have been unable to trace it.

**Setup: Node V8.10.0, expressjs, mongodb**

I don't believe it to be part of the API endpoints but rather an importer script.

You can see the error I am getting here: https://dpaste.org/zs2S

It's always a

> Error: async hook stack has become corrupted

The below is the code I am running. Its purpose is to use ***chokidar*** to watch a directory. (Previously used *fs.watch* but changed to ***chokidar*** due to thinking it was an fs error but still getting it) And when a file is changed, use csv2json to get the file and return it as a json object.

Once this object has been retrieved, insert it into mongo, first by adding it with the name _Update as a new collection. Drop the current live one, then rename the new, removing _Update, therefore making it live.

I use pm2 to run the app. It runs for a while but will always crash at some point with the above error.

```
//require the mongojs package to setup db connection
var mongojs = require("mongojs");
//require the csvtojson package to convert the CSV file
var csv = require("csvtojson");
require("log-timestamp");
const chokidar = require("chokidar");
var config = 
require("../../config/config").get(process.env.NODE_ENV);
var db = mongojs(config.database);

exports.import = function() {
  // Initialize watcher.
  const watcher = chokidar.watch(config.watchfolder, {
    ignored: /(^|[\/\\])\../, // ignore dotfiles
    persistent: true,
    awaitWriteFinish: true
  });

  // Something to use when events are received.
  const log = console.log.bind(console);

  watcher.on("change", path => {
    log(`File ${path} has been changed`);

    let requiredCollection = config.sources.find(o => o.csvFile === path);

    csv()
      .fromFile(path)
      .then(jsonArrObj => {
        if (requiredCollection.collectionName.includes("RiverLevels")) {
          for (var item in jsonArrObj) {
            if (jsonArrObj[item].Movement == "S") {
              jsonArrObj[item].Movement = "Steady";
            }
            if (jsonArrObj[item].Movement == "R") {
              jsonArrObj[item].Movement = "Rising";
            }
            if (jsonArrObj[item].Movement == "F") {
              jsonArrObj[item].Movement = "Falling";
            }
            if (jsonArrObj[item].PrimaryStation == "1") {
              db.collection("riverOverview").replaceOne(
                { StationName: jsonArrObj[item].StationName },
                jsonArrObj[item]
              );
              console.log("Primary Station updated into riverOverview");
            }
          }
        }

        //Create new collection with _update
        db.createCollection(
          requiredCollection.collectionName + "_Update",
          function(err) {
            //Insert data fulled from file
            db.collection(requiredCollection.collectionName + "_Update").insert(
              jsonArrObj,
              function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                  console.log(err);
                }
                console.log(
                  requiredCollection.collectionName + "_Update added to mongo"
                );

                //Drop the current DB
                db.collection(requiredCollection.collectionName).drop(function(
                  err
                ) {
                  if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                  }
                  console.log(
                    "Old " + requiredCollection.collectionName + " deleted."
                  );
                  //rename update DB to make it the live one.
                  db.collection(
                    requiredCollection.collectionName + "_Update"
                  ).rename(requiredCollection.collectionName, function(
                    err,
                    collection
                  ) {
                    if (err) {
                      console.log(err);
                    } else {
                      console.log("rename Results: " + collection.namespace);
                    }
                    console.log(
                      requiredCollection.collectionName +
                        "_Update renamed to: " +
                        requiredCollection.collectionName
                    );
                  });
                });
              }
            );
          }
        );
      });
  });
};
```

Comment: Right now your code is swallowing errors. Most of the time, whenever an error happens you should not continue executing the code afterwards. By doing so, you could create a very weird and unpredictable state of your application. Basically, every callback should do something like `if(err) throw err;` and it should show you when/if your code is breaking and prevent any further tasks from executing.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is taking too long to elaborate, which means that multiple requests are filling the `async queue` until it can't handle it.

Best course of action is to handle the exception, retrying with some delay, using a `timeout`.

```
let time = 0; 

try {
    // Do your stuff
    if ( time > 0 ) {
        time -= 1000;
    }
}
catch (e) {
    time += 1000;
    setTimeout(() => {
        // Do your stuff
    }, time);
}
```

Of course, this is a workaround. You should try to decrease the amount of time it takes to perform the action.

One more thing: you are using Node.js 8. Version 8 is out of its final maintenance window and is no longer supported. You should consider upgrading to version 12. Upgrading to the latest version might also solve the async issue above without using the workaround.